# Hibernate Inheritance.JOINED generated FK name

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, myisam

I am currently trying to use inheritance within Hibernate and came across `InheritanceType.JOINED`. I like the idea of concentrating all data in one table and sharing IDs rather than having duplicate columns in all the sub type tables (@MappedSuperClass). But Hibernate automatically generates indexes on my sub class tables on the `id` column like `FK_idx3wiwdm8yp2qkkddi726n8o` everytime I initialize my Hibernate singleton. I noticed that by hitting the 64 key limit on my MySQL Table as the names are generated differently on every startup.

What is the proper way to handle this? Can this be fixed by annotations? What else could I try?

I know that there are countless similar Questions on SO but haven't been able to identify one solving my specific problem.

I am not going to disable hbm2ddl.auto during dev mode.

I am using MyISAM. There are no actual Foreign Keys. This is why Hibernate generates default indexes, I think. Anyway, the problem would be identical with InnoDB and real Foreign Keys as the names would still be quite random. Or maybe Hibernate would actually check for existence in this case. I don't really see, why it does not do this on MyISAM tables.

As I hit similar problems before, the solution could also be to specify a name for that single-column index. But how?

**Super Class: FolderItem**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class FolderItem implements Comparable<FolderItem>
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    protected int       id;
    protected String    name;
    @OneToOne
    @ForeignKey(name = "fkParent")
    protected Folder    parent;
    ...
}
```

**Sub Class: Folder**

```
@Entity
public class Folder extends FolderItem
{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    @OrderBy(value = "sortOrder")
    private List<FolderItem>    children;
    ...
}
```

**What I tried**

- add `@Index` to `FolderItem.id` - this created an index on the `FolderItem` table as one would expect, but didn't affect the `Folder` table
- copy `protected int id;` to `Folder` and tried to add an @Index to it, which resulted in an Exception similar to "duplicate definition of ID"
- add `@Table(appliesTo = "Folder", indexes = { @Index(name = "fkId", columnNames = { "id" }) })` to `Folder` class, which actually created my specified index as expected, but still created it's own FK_9xcia6idnwqdi9xx8ytea40h3 which is identical to mine, except for the name

Answer (score 0):

Try `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "foler_item_id")` annotation for Folder class.